Error Code [There is no current event loop. loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()] in Telegram Bot Reminder Script
I'm new to coding with Python and I'm trying to create a Telegram reminder bot for my Duolingo practice. I used ChatGPT to help me with the code, but I can't seem to fix an error I'm encountering. I'm running my code on Visual Studio Code on my MacBook, and I receive the following error:
There is no current event loop. loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
Here is the general code I'm using (note: I have removed the API_TOKEN and CHAT_ID for privacy):
import logging
import schedule
import time
import asyncio  # <-- Make sure to import asyncio
from telegram import Bot
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Your bot's API token
API_TOKEN = 'YOUR_API_TOKEN'

# Your boyfriend's chat ID (replace with his actual chat ID)
CHAT_ID = 'YOUR_CHAT_ID'

async def start(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    await update.message.reply_text('Hi! I will remind you to do your Duolingo.')

async def remind_duolingo():
    """Send a reminder message."""
    bot = Bot(API_TOKEN)
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text='Hey, don’t forget to do your Duolingo lesson today!')

async def main():
    """Start the bot."""
    application = Application.builder().token(API_TOKEN).build()

    # Add command handler to start the bot
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

    # Start polling for updates
    await application.run_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Schedule the reminder every day at a specific time
    schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(remind_duolingo)  # Set your preferred time

    # Create an event loop explicitly and run the main function in it
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(main())  # Schedule the main function to run in the event loop

    # Run the scheduler in a loop
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

